# Таблица в [lsfusion] с динамическим количеством колонок

Tags: таблицы, lsfusion

Как сформировать электронную таблицу с динамическим количеством колонок и вложенными заголовками ?

[image: Пример таблицы]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого необходимо использовать атрибуты COLUMNS при добавлении свойства на форму.

Например :

```
MODULE Main;

CLASS Row;
name = DATA STRING (Row);

CLASS Column;
name = DATA STRING (Column);

p1 = DATA NUMERIC (Row, Column);
p2 = DATA NUMERIC (Row, Column);
p3 = DATA NUMERIC (Row, Column);

FORM toExcel
    OBJECTS c = Column
    OBJECTS r = Row
    PROPERTIES(r) name
    
    PROPERTIES(r, c) COLUMNS (c) HEADER name(c) p1, p2, p3 
;
exportToExcel () {
    PRINT toExcel XLSX;
}
FORM test
    OBJECTS r = Row
    PROPERTIES(r) name, NEW, DELETE
    
    OBJECTS c = Column
    PROPERTIES(c) name, NEW, DELETE
    
    PROPERTIES(r, c) p1, p2, p3
    PROPERTIES() exportToExcel
;
NAVIGATOR {
    NEW test;
}
```

Затем нужно создать [печатное представление](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/How-to_Reports/) формы следующего вида (в формате jrxml) :

[image: JasperReports]

В результате при нажатии кнопки выгрузки в Excel будет электронная таблица вида :

[image: Результат]